# Netlify deploy react application breaks on parameters

Tags: node.js, reactjs, netlify

I am having trouble putting an app in production with Netlify. The app works smoothly locally, but when deploying to Netlify I am having trouble with this endpoint:

```
mywebsite.com/confirm?token=aaf21b43849e45d5576c6e8a3278d1c4&email=test@test.com
```

The page is directly not found.

If I enter

```
mywebsite.com/confirm?token=aaf21b43849e45d5576c6e8a3278d1c4&email=test@test
```

(without the .com) it works fine.

It seems like a Netflify bug/limitation, but I would like to confirm with a more experienced audience (you).

Thank you very much

Comment: Not a fix suggestion: Just curious, have you tried flipping the order of the parameters?

Comment: yes, I've tried. I have solved it by encrypting the email, and the decrypting again

Comment: What he is saying is that it's really weird to begin your GET parameters with a "&" instead of a "?". and after that you usually uri-encode any parameters that are likely to contain symbols. So in your case: `mywebsite.com/confirm?token=aaf21b43849e45d5576c6e8a3278d1c4&email=test%40test.com`

Comment: I misspelled in the example... I confirm I was using '?' and then '&' for adding parameters. Editing now.

Answer (score 0):

My current workaround has been to encrypt the email and decrypt it again so no dots are in the URL. Not the best solution but it works.